# Sqlite - Insert gives error - Invalid cast exception - "Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'."

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

```
var idParam = new SQLiteParameter("@idParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = insertData.ID };
var userIdParam = new SQLiteParameter("@userIdParam", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = insertData.Uid };
var applicationNameParam = new SQLiteParameter("@applicationNameParam", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = insertData.Application };
var eventNameParam = new SQLiteParameter("@eventNameParam", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = insertData.EventName };
var clientTokenParam = new SQLiteParameter("@clientTokenParam", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = insertData.ClientToken };
var versionParam = new SQLiteParameter("@versionParam", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = insertData.Version };
var dateTimeParam = new SQLiteParameter("@dateTimeParam", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = insertData.DateTime };
var dataParam = new SQLiteParameter("@dataParam", SqlDbType.Text) { Value = insertData.Data };

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO DATAOUT (id, uid, application, eventname, clienttoken, version, datetime, data)" +
    " VALUES ('@idParam','@userIdParam','@applicationNameParam','@eventNameParam','@clientTokenParam','@versionParam',@dateTimeParam,'@dataParam')",Connection);
command.Parameters.Add(idParam);
command.Parameters.Add(userIdParam);
command.Parameters.Add(applicationNameParam);
command.Parameters.Add(eventNameParam);
command.Parameters.Add(clientTokenParam);
command.Parameters.Add(versionParam);
command.Parameters.Add(dateTimeParam);
command.Parameters.Add(dataParam);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am trying to debug this INSERT but I am not having much luck. Why is sqllite trying to cast my datetime to an int?? The database schema is expecting a datetime object. Is there a way to see the insert command text as it is sent to the db?

Here is a look at the Types that I am trying to insert:

```
public string Uid { get; private set; }
public string Application { get; private set; }
public string EventName { get; private set; }
public string ClientToken { get; private set; }
public string Version { get; private set; }
public DateTime DateTime { get; private set; }
public string Data { get; private set; }
```

Here is the an example of the insert:

> INSERT INTO DATAOUT (id, uid,
>   application, eventname, clienttoken,
>   version, datetime, data) VALUES ('
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000','123abcd','My
>   Application','','Test
>   Client','1.0.0','1/1/2000','[{"id":"alpha_123","question":"ronunciations
>   in pre-classical times or in non-Attic
>   dialects. For
>   det","answer":"nunciations
>   "},{"id":"beta_456","question":"official
>   documents such as laws
>   an","answer":"or
>   modif"},{"id":"gamma_789","question":"
>   maintained or modified slightly to fit
>   Greek phonology; thus,
>   ?","answer":"iation of
>   Attic"},{"id":"delta_098","question":"econstructed
>   pronunciation of Attic in the late 5th
>   an","answer":"unciation of
>   "},{"id":"epsilon_076","question":"erent
>   stylistic variants, with the
>   descending tail either going straight
>   down o","answer":"Whole
>   bunch"},{"id":"zeta_054","question":"rough
>   breathing when it begins a word.
>   Another diacritic use","answer":"other
>   dia"}]')

The last value is a JSON string. The dateTime field is apparently the problem (7th param). For the example above I just added the text '1/1/2011'. The code is constructing the insert via the parameters. The datetime parameter has a valid date in the debugger.

When I inspect the parameter,"dateTimeParam" the debugger shows dbType = Int32. What's up with that?

**UPDATE**

Removed the quotes around the parameters in the insert statement. It results in the string literals, @paramname to be inserted. 
Thanks!

Comment: Which parameter are you talking about? Only the `dateTimeParam`? What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: What are the actual values that you want to insert?

Comment: What is the structure of the table itself?

Comment: Every column is a varchar or text except for the date which is DateTime

Comment: Why are your parameters surrounded by quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you don't have quotes around `@dateTimeParam` in query, and query parser assumes it is an `int`.

**What really bugs me though is why you surround parameters by quotes at all.**

Try this:

```
var command = new SQLiteCommand (
   "INSERT INTO DATAOUT (id, uid, application, eventname, clienttoken, version, datetime, data)" +
    " VALUES (@idParam, @userIdParam, @applicationNameParam, @eventNameParam, @clientTokenParam, @versionParam, @dateTimeParam, @dataParam)",
    Connection);
```

**UPDATE**

I have no idea what is causing the issue. I tried to mimic [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751172/system-data-sqlite-parameter-issue/751393#751393). Does this help?

```
var command = new SQLiteCommand (
    "INSERT INTO DATAOUT (id, uid, application, eventname, clienttoken, version, datetime, data)" +
    " VALUES (@idParam,@userIdParam,@applicationNameParam,@eventNameParam,@clientTokenParam,@versionParam,@dateTimeParam,@dataParam)",
    Connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idParam", insertData.ID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userIdParam", insertData.Uid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@applicationNameParam", insertData.Application);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventNameParam", insertData.EventName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientTokenParam", insertData.ClientToken);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@versionParam", insertData.Version);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTimeParam", insertData.DateTime);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataParam", insertData.Data);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Actually the quotes '' are wrong. This is inserting the string literal of @paraName in the db.. doh

Comment: I suggest you **remove** *all* quotes, not replace them with `"`.

Comment: The now the exception is Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: This is odd, but I'll make a rough guess: did you try instead wrapping @dateTimeParam in single quotes, like the rest of parameters?

Comment: I saw it just now.. let me try it

Answer (score 1):

My problem was caused by using the parameter data type of: System.Data.DbType.DateTime2 and the .NET Sqlite api does not recognize this enumeration.