# Storing Data in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Is there a way to store TEXT in SQLite database without SQLite trying to parse it?
Ran into a problem where when you store TEXT that is similar to SQLite query, it tries to parse it for some reason.

Query I use to save TEXT: `"insert into tableName (Name, DateCreated, Reminder, Content) values ('name', 'currentDate', 'reminder', 'content')".`

Similar text I'm trying to save: `"SELECT NAME FROM sqlite_master WHERE TYPE='table' ORDER BY NAME".`

When i try to save something like that, it says: Error: SQL logic error or missing database near "table":syntax error

Please note that values (name, currentDate, reminder, content) are not hard coded, they are passed as strings. actual code is like below:

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("insert into " + cateName + " (Name, DateCreated, Reminder, Content) values ('" + noteName + "', '" + currentDate + "', '" + reminder + "', '" + content + "')", connection);
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Please show the code you're using to save the values. Your INSERT statement at the moment is hard-coded to character literals... I'm sure that's not what you're actually doing. (I suspect the problem is that you should be using parameterized SQL, but we can't tell without seeing your code.)

Comment: You have an extra " in the 2nd text, was that a typo when preparing this question?

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry, just updated the code.

Comment: @waTeim, sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Sounds like you're facing a self-induced SQL injection attack :-)

Comment: In addition to Jon Skeet see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/751172/2655508

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, you are right, that is what it looks like, thinking of it now you can probably get info from the database like that which is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspect, the problem is that you're putting your values directly into the SQL - without even trying to escape them. **Don't do that.** As well as the problems you're seeing, you've opened yourself up to a [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com). Use *parameterized SQL* instead, and specify values for the parameters.

For example:

```
// It's not clear what cateName is, but I'll assume *that* bit is valid...
string sql = new SQLiteCommand("insert into " + cateName +
     " (Name, DateCreated, Reminder, Content) values " +
     "(@Name, @DateCreated, @Reminder, @Content)");

using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SQLiteType.Text).Value = noteName;
    command.Parameters.Add("@DateCreated", SQLiteType.DateTime).Value = currentDate;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Reminder", SQLiteType.Text).Value = reminder;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Content", SQLiteType.Text).Value = content;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, cateName is the tableName variable, thanks for your explanation, however command.Parameters.Add does not accept SQLiteType, only accepts DbType which doesn't contain TEXT or DateTime.

Comment: Sort of a got it working, by using DbType.String, saves the content fine. Should i use the same (Paramaeterized) method to retrieve data from the database? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @NetInfo: Yes, you should use parameterized SQL for *all* dynamic values. It helps in all kinds of ways.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Can't thank you enough for helping out.