# How to make this SQL statement work using where

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have the following code, I want to make a query with the where statement, but it does not give me any results, could you help me

```
public List<Persona> Listarwhere()
{
    List<Persona> oLista = new List<Persona>();

    using (SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection(cadena))
    {
        conexion.Open();

        Persona obj = new Persona();
        Form1 idcliente = new Form1();
        //int cliente = int.Parse(idcliente.txtidpersona.Text);

        string query = "select IdPersona, Nombre, Apellido, Telefono from Persona where idpersona = @idpersona";

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conexion);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@idpersona", idcliente.txtidpersona.Text));
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                oLista.Add(new Persona()
                    {
                        IdPersona = int.Parse(dr["IdPersona"].ToString()),
                        Nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString(),
                        Apellido = dr["Apellido"].ToString(),
                        Telefono = dr["Telefono"].ToString()
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    return oLista;
}
```

I need to pass the data of this query in several textbox

Comment: Check if this is your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/9264141/5449226. Also did you try running the query directly on the tables, does it return any rows.

Comment: @leangaurav this example does not accommodate the problem raised, thanks

Comment: @JohnG The query is correct, it seems a bit confusing that the client id field is here, but it is part of the test I do, I can omit it and nothing happens, the question is that I can't get the query to work.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code… `Form1 idcliente = new Form1();` … ? the form `idclient` is never open and I am betting that the line of code… `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@idpersona", idcliente.txtidpersona.Text));` … is returning an “empty” parameter. Have you checked what `idcliente.txtidpersona.Text ` is returning? Otherwise the code works in my tests.

Comment: @Oscar2017 try to the the generated query in database directly and see if it’s returning the rows or not?

Comment: Put your cursor on the `cmd.Parameters.Add` line, press F9 so it goes red, run the program, do whatever you need to do to make this code run. The code will stop with a yellow bar. Point your mouse at the word "Text" to inspect its value - you'll probably pretty quickly see the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to pass in your 'idpersona' as a parameter to your method. ... maybe something like this:

```cs
public List<Persona> Listarwhere(string id) // or (int id)
{
    List<Persona> oLista = new List<Persona>();

    using (SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection(cadena))
    {
        conexion.Open();

        Persona obj = new Persona();
        //Form1 idcliente = new Form1();
        //int cliente = int.Parse(idcliente.txtidpersona.Text);

        string query = "select IdPersona, Nombre, Apellido, Telefono from Persona where idpersona = @idpersona";

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conexion);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@idpersona", id));
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                oLista.Add(new Persona()
                    {
                        IdPersona = int.Parse(dr["IdPersona"].ToString()),
                        Nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString(),
                        Apellido = dr["Apellido"].ToString(),
                        Telefono = dr["Telefono"].ToString()
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    return oLista;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation